# How is  crabgrass removed from lawns?

Tags: lawn, lawn-repair, crabgrass, seeds

I have some crabgrass in various patches in my lawn that I would like to remove.  At the same time, I would like to fill in some patches (and the crabgrass locations) with new grass seed.  I can buy some fertilizer with crabgrass preventer, but I assume that this will make it so the good grass seed does not grow.

Is there any way to kill crabgrass and grow good grass in its place?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Theres a product called Seed Starter Fertilizer + Crabgrass Preventer 11-23-10.  It is by greenview and can be found here: http://www.greenviewfertilizer.com/store/Seed-Starter-Fertilizer-Crabgrass-Preventer-P44C12.aspx?UserID=7835774&SessionID=gohk6QYKA9s8imKw4jl0

This prevents the crabgrass and at the same time promotes grass seed germination.  The issue with this is it can only be used to **PREVENT** crab grass.  It sounds like you have a good amount of it already established.  In most cases any fertilizer that contains a weed killer also prohibits seeds from germinating to create new grass.

There really is no answer to do this all at the same time.  The best thing to do is to first get rid of all the current crab grass.  Whether it be with a Scotts product or actually just yanking that stuff out.  Once you've got all of it (and it is hard work), apply a crab grass preventer (Scotts or Greenview).  You shouldn't reseed until about 4 mowings (in weeks time that is equivalent to 6-8 weeks).  So we are looking at close to a month and a half before you can really being to think about seeding again.

There is ONE other option I can think of.  But please note I have never tried this.  There is a product called **Tupersan Crabgrass Preventer** http://hubpages.com/hub/Tupersan that is the *only* product that can prevent crabgrass that will allow you to seed your lawn at the same time. Tupersan is very effective against crabgrass and will not harm grass seeds.  But I think tupersan is very expensive it can get upto 80 bucks a bag.  Here is a bag I found for close to 70: http://www.turftrust.com/index.php?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=27&category_id=3&vmcchk=1&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=1

Good luck